# Domain Shared Contacts API to create external contacts using python + service account (client library)

Tags: python, rest, google-people-api, google-shared-contacts

I want to use  [Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts?csw=1) as part of python client library.

The flow that I use in other cases:
Create credentials:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(....)
```

'Create' a service object which I execute later

```
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(service_name, api_version,credentials=credentials)
```

In the case of Domain Shared Contacts API I dont know what service_name or api_version to use [Google API Discovery Service](https://discovery.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis) if any.
Is it possible to create/update/remove external contacts for a domain using the contact OR people APIs?

If not, the process of utilising this API is to create requests in your codebase [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) to REST endpoints like:
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/example.com/full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem only by using the [Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts)

1. I created a service account.
2. Prepared an authorized (HTTP/REST) API call using the example [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). Special attention to *Additional claims* **sub**.
3. Since I am using Python, I installed [pyjwt](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and used it to create and sign my JWT. As a secret, I used the service_account.private_key:

   ```
   jwt.encode(jwt_claim_set, secret, algorithm="RS256")
   ```

Then depending on the use case (get contacts, create one..). I assigned the Google token (signed JWT) to my request.

Example:

```
endpoint = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{}/{}'.format(your_own_domain, projection_value)
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
gsuite_get_response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Would someone be interested in having a python. lib for this?